# Does Postgres lock more rows than the limit provided?

Tags: postgresql

If the `LIMIT` is applied to the rows returned from a query, does this mean that more rows could be locked that are not returned?

Like this:

```
select * from myTable where status = 'READY' limit 10 FOR UPDATE
```

If there are 1000 rows in a status of `READY`, does it row lock them all but only return 10?

I am seeing quite a costly `-> LockRows` on my explain plan and trying to understand why.

Thanks

Comment: You may be able to use the information from this link, to find out: https://habr.com/en/company/postgrespro/blog/503008/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/explicit-locking.html), it seems pretty clear that only the actual records returned by your select query would be locked:

> FOR UPDATE causes the rows retrieved by the SELECT statement to be locked as though for update. This prevents them from being locked, modified or deleted by other transactions until the current transaction ends.

That being said, one possible explanation for why the `LockRows` operation seems so costly is that, in order to isolate the 10 records you want for locking, it first has to do a sort to implement `LIMIT`.  This is an operation which involves the entire table, so for a large table, and without an index to help, this could take some time.

Let's say this were your actual query:

```sql
select * from myTable where status = 'READY' order by some_col limit 10 FOR UPDATE
```

This query would benefit from the following index:

```sql
create index idx on myTable (status, some_col);
```

The first column in the index `status` would let Postgres discard records not matching the `WHERE` filter.  After this, the index also covers `some_col`, which means Postgres could easily find the limit 10 records you want already in the correct order.

Comment: I also read that row locking takes place in the physical row (not in RAM), which I guess could also increase the time.

Comment: Thanks guys, yes Tim you are correct I'm using an `order by random()` to reduce the chances of multiple threads attempting to lock the same row, and that seems to be where the cost jumps up.

Comment: @Jimmy Let me update my answer and give you a way to tune your query, which should help across the entire execution plan.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen thanks, looks great. Would that index also get used for something like this? `select min(some_col) from myTable where status = 'blah' group by status` ?

Comment: The index you would want for this query would be something like `(status, some_col)`, so yes, it should also work for your query above.

Comment: @Jimmy "*to reduce the chances of multiple threads attempting to lock the same row*" - then why not use `skip locked`?

Comment: Thanks @a_horse_with_no_name, must have missed that when reading the docs, have swapped to `skip locked` now. Cheers guys, very helpful.